# I threw CompletionException, but ExecutionException arises. Why?

Tags: java, spring, completable-future

Below is exception handling java code using CompletableFuture.
I intentionally raise `InvalidParameterException` in the subthread.

```
    public CompletableFuture<Object> myCompletableFuture() throws CompletionException {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                    // While doing some tasks...
                    // InvalidParameterException arises in here...
                    // ...
                });
            } catch (Exception e){ 
                throw new CompletionException(e); 
            }
        });
    }
```

(Edited) And above Future is activated by calling `whenCompleteAsync`.

```
DeferredResult<Object> myFunc() throws CompletionException {
      DeferredResult<Object> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
      myCompletableFuture().whenCompleteAsync((result, executor) -> {
         if (executor != null) {
            deferredResult.setErrorResult(executor);
         } else {
            deferredResult.setResult(result);
         }
      });
      return deferredResult;
}
```

***What I'v expected:***
`java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: InvalidParameterException(param:myparam)`

***Actual:***
`java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: InvalidParameterException(param:myparam)`

***Question:***
Why exception wraps `ExecutionException` instead of `CompletionException`?

Comment: @user16320675 Thank you for the comment. I used `whenCompleteAsync()` instead of `get()`, and added the code snippet related to this.

Comment: I tried your code and got a `CompletionException`. Please provide a [mre]. For it to be minimal, you should probably remove the Spring/`DeferredResult` part as they don’t seem to be related to the problem.

Comment: As a side note, it’s very confusing to name a parameter `executor` when it is actually a `Throwable`.